# Using ST_Intersects in OGR2OGR

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'm running GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10.

The following displays all the attributes in my shapefile on stdout:

> /opt/gdal-custom/bin/ogr2ogr -f CSV /vsistdout/ foo.shp -sql "SELECT *  FROM foo "

However, if I add the WHERE clause  `WHERE ST_Intersects(GEOMETRY,BuildCircleMbr(0, 0, 10000,  4326))` I get `ERROR 1: Undefined function 'ST_Intersects' used.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your dataset I can't be 100% sure, but I'd wager you can solve this by adding `-dialect sqlite` since `ST_Intersects` is a [Spatialite SQL function](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html).

Your command should be

```
/opt/gdal-custom/bin/ogr2ogr -f CSV /vsistdout/ foo.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM foo "
```

Comment: Ok that works. My next step was to use BuildCircleMbr, which required me to recompile gdal with `--with-spatialite=yes`

Answer (score 1):

I guess that ST_Intersects(*Geom1*, *Geom2*) will test a spatial relationship between two elements and return a boolean (True or False), what you need here is probably ST_Intersection(*Geom1*, *Geom2*) if you want to create a geometry (resulting of the intersections of the two others passed in arguments).

(If it is ST_Intersects() that you need, it should probably be after the WHERE clause, like "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ST_Intersects(Geom1, Geom2)")

(or maybe if you want to create geometry for self intersections you can try the SpatiaLite/LWGEOM function ST_SelfIntersections(*Geom*) but I'm not sure that you can call it using ogr2ogr, even with *-dialect SQLite* enabled)

Comment: I should have described what I really wanted to do. Was working on getting ST_Intersects() working at all first.